# I'm trying to write some test with firstore and swiftui, I can create and read, but now i don't know how to list unique data,

Tags: firebase, listview, google-cloud-firestore, duplicates, swiftui

You can see I have two fields in this document, "ing01", and "nameReceta" every document in this collection has the same name fields, in the field "ing01" I have "Pimienta" in description, my app it allows more documents whit "Pimienta" in "ing01" and this is fine, but when I want to list it I need list only one "Pimienta", how can I remove the others?

[image]

I have this data model

```
struct ModeloRecetasIng : Identifiable, Hashable, Equatable {
   var id: String
   var nameReceta: String
   var ing01: String
}
```

and here I get the data, and it works fine.

```
class ingredientesAdd : ObservableObject {
    //    @Published var datosNoDupl = [DataNoDuplicates]()
    @Published var datas = [ModeloRecetasIng]()

    init() {
        // Borra el cache
        let settings = FirestoreSettings()
        settings.isPersistenceEnabled = false

        let db = Firestore.firestore()
        db.settings = settings

        // Borra el cache
        db.collection("DespensaIng01").getDocuments { (snap, err) in
            if err != nil {
                print((err?.localizedDescription)!)
                return
            }

            for i in snap!.documents
            {
                let id = i.documentID
                let nameReceta = i.get("nameReceta") as! String
                let ing01 = i.get("ing01") as! String

//
                self.datas.append(ModeloRecetasIng(id: id, nameReceta: nameReceta, ing01: ing01))
            }

            // I'm trying to use set but it doesn't work
            let uniqueUnordered = Array(Set(self.datas))
            self.datas = uniqueUnordered
            print(self.datas)
        }
    }
}
```

When I get my Print I see this

```
Pimienta
Pimienta
Zanahoria
Zanahoria
Zanahoria
```

and I only want this

```
Pimienta
Zanahoria
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.. just using a custom ID in firestore, and no more duplicates and now i need to sum de quantity only